# Handling function callbacks in TypeScript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React app using TypeScript, I'm trying to have a child object call a function in the parent. I'm having some issues getting the typings right. Here's a trimmed down example:

```
function RequestVisitAddress(onAddressSelected: (address: GoogleAddressParser) => void) {
  const [selectedAddress, setSelectedAddress] = useState<GoogleAddressParser | null>(null);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    onAddressSelected(selectedAddress as GoogleAddressParser);
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={onSubmit} />
  );
}
```

```
function Parent() {
  const onAddressSelected = (address: GoogleAddressParser) => {
    console.log(address);
  };

  return (
    <RequestVisitAddress onAddressSelected={onAddressSelected} />
  );
}
```

When the button is clicked in the RequestVisitAddress component, I would like to run the onAddressSelected method in Parent. However, I'm getting the following warning on the onAddressSelected attribute in the Parent component:

```
Type '{ onAddressSelected: (address: GoogleAddressParser) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ((address: GoogleAddressParser) => void)'.
  Property 'onAddressSelected' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ((address: GoogleAddressParser) => void)'.ts(2322)
```

What do I need to adjust to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `RequestVisitAddress` props are not correctly typed. This is what you are looking for :

```
type Props = {
  onAddressSelected: (address: GoogleAddressParser) => void,
}

function RequestVisitAddress({onAddressSelected}: Props) {
  const [selectedAddress, setSelectedAddress] = useState<GoogleAddressParser | null>(null);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    onAddressSelected(selectedAddress as GoogleAddressParser);
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={onSubmit} />
  );
}
```

You get all your props in an Object, so you need to destructure `onAddressSelected` from the props to be able to access it.

Comment: Perfect, I went down the wrong path completely. Thanks!